# How can I make a fixed element a bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The question might sound a little bit complex but it unfortunately is rather a simple question i cant find an answer to.
The situation looks like this: I made a menu and fixed it. This menu is an unordered list with list elements in it. I put the menu on the right by setting 'right: 0;' in css. Now I would like to make the menu an actual bar because at the moment it is nothing more than a simple rectangle that only covers a corner of the screen. What I want it to do is being a bar on the top that goes from left to right. Dont get me wrong, the list elements still should be in the right corner, but as it has a background I want this background to be seen as a wide bar so it looks more like a menu bar.
Maybe there is a setting for 'padding-left:' that can realize this as i only would need the padding to be as wide as the screen width so it covers everything from left to right.

My code (edited down to the menu part) looks something like this:

.html:

```
...
<body>
    <section id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#contactdetails">
                    Contact details
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#rental">
                    Rental
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#informations">
                    Informations
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#home">
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

.css:

```
#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #222222;
    
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 0;
}

#menu li {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #EAECEE;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    padding: 14px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #menu li a {
        font-size: 0.9em;
        padding: 12px 6px;
    }
}

#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}
```

Also, there is a second problem that maybe could be solved with a menu bar: On 'home', I put an image that somehow is prioritized to the menu bar which means it covers the menu bar partly which also isnt very nice. I havent done anything in particular to it other than a slider as there are multiple images you are able to slide. I would like to avoid putting the code here as that would mean I had to edit the whole source code into English but if its needed to solve this second problem just tell me and I will edit it into here. I am just hoping that there is a obvious complication I dont know about that somebody can tell me.

As Im pretty new to html I would also be glad if you would point out any other mistakes I made.

Thanks for reading this!
Xydru

EDIT:
Here is the code of the image:
.html:

```
<section id="home">
    <h1>Name of the Website</h1>
        
    <!-- Slideshow container -->
    <div class="slideshow-container">

        <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 7</div>
            <img src="img/home_1.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 7</div>
            <img src="img/home_2.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 7</div>
            <img src="img/home_3.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
                
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">4 / 7</div>
            <img src="img/home_4.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
                
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">5 / 7</div>
            <img src="img/home_5.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
                
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">6 / 7</div>
            <img src="img/home_6.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
                
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">7 / 7</div>
            <img src="img/home_7.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- The dots/circles -->
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(7)"></span>
    </div>
</section>

... (at the end of 'body')

<script src="slider.js"></script>
```

.css:

```
/* Slider */

* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "prev button" to the left*/
.prev {
    left: 5px;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
    right: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/4 etc) */
.numbertext {
    color: #424242;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4}
    to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4}
    to {opacity: 1}
}
```

slider.js:

```
// Normal Slide
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: have you tried width: 100%?

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Unfortunately there still is the second problem that lets my image cover up the menu bar :(

Comment: can you add ur code with the image here?

Comment: I've added it now, I hope this should be enough

Comment: Add z-index to both, higher number for ur nav section

Answer (score 1):

Since the target is the holder of the list, then the `position` property should style the `#menu` and not the list first, so we move the `properties` from the `ul` to the `#menu`.

Now, *fixed positioning* elements takes the width of it's content, by default, so we **add** the other properties like (`top`, `right` and `left`) with the values of `0` and `width: 100%;` to "stretch" it to the sides.

```
#menu {
    background-color: #222222;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

**Code:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#menu {
    background-color: #222222;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu li {
    float: right;
}

#menu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #EAECEE;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    padding: 14px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #menu li a {
        font-size: 0.9em;
        padding: 12px 6px;
    }
}

#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<section id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#contactdetails">
                Contact details
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#rental">
                Rental
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#informations">
                Informations
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#home">
                Home
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```